# a probability question related to computing the variance of a specific pattern

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, stochastic-processes

With respect to a given sequence of points $\{X_1, ... X_t, ...X_n\}$.

[image]

I can understand why $E[S]= \frac{n-1}{2}$. But how to get that $Var[S]$.

Comment: did you try finding $S-\mathbf{E}S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=2,\dots,n$ let $Y_i = 1$ if $X_i>X_{i-1}$ and $Y_i = 0$ otherwise, so that $S = \sum_{i=2}^{n} Y_i$.

Then $\text{Var}[S] = \sum_{i=2}^{n}\sum_{j=2}^{n} \text{Cov}[Y_i,Y_j]$. What is $\text{Cov}[Y_i,Y_j]$ when $i=j$? When $i$ and $j$ differ by $1$? When $i$ and $j$ differ by more than $1$?

Try filling in the proof yourself!

Comment: I did my analysis based on your hint, which is posted in the next. But I did not get the right answer. I am not sure which part of my analysis is incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my analysis, but did not get $(n+1)/12$. Which part of my analysis is wrong?

$Var[S]=Var(\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i)=\sum_{i=2}^nVar(Y_i)+\sum_{i\neq j}Cov(Y_i, Y_j)$

In accordance with the definition of $Y_i$ and $\{X_t\}$ is IID. I think $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ is uncorrelated when $i\neq j$. Therefore the second summation term, $\sum_{i\neq j}Cov(Y_i, Y_j)=0$. I only need to take care $Var(Y_i)$. $Y_i$ only has two possibilities: 0 and 1, and each with probability of 0.5. Hence $Var(Y_i)=E[Y_i^2]-(E[Y_i])^2=0.25$.

So $Var[S]=Var(\sum_{i=2}^{n}Y_i)=\sum_{i=2}^nVar(Y_i)=\frac{n-1}{4}$

Comment: You're close! I agree with you about the case where $i=j$, and when $i$ and $j$ differ by more than one. However, I disagree that $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are uncorrelated when $i$ and $j$, e.g. when $i=2$ and $j=3$.

Comment: I got it, $Cov(Y_i, Y_{i+1})= E[Y_iY_{i+1}]-E[Y_i]E[Y_{i+1}]=1/6-1/4$ Thanks!